# Mailing list scheduler

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, scheduled-tasks, scheduling, newsletter

I have an asp script which I use to send newsletters to different mailing lists. At the moment I click a send button via html to mail everyone in the mailing list. Instead I'd prefer to be able to schedule the sending of a newsletter rather than sending it instantly.

How might I do this on iis7. I am experienced in programming in other languages so I'm open to all suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to create a scheduled task on the server that calls your page on a defined schedule.

You can create a VBScript that will request your web page. Then create a scheduled task that calls this script with the URL as a parameter. So if you save the following script as WEBEXEC.VBS then you would call it in your scheduled task as "WEBEXEC.VBS http://www.test.com/mypage.asp".

```
Option Explicit
Dim objWinHttp, strURL
strURL = WScript.Arguments(0)
Set objWinHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
objWinHttp.Open "GET", strURL
objWinHttp.Send
Set objWinHttp = Nothing
```

If you don't have access to create scheduled tasks on the server you could do the same thing on any other computer that is always turned on and connected to the Internet.

Another option is to use ASP.NET which will alow you to run a task in Golbal.asax that can call your URL on a schedule. The problem with this is that if your website is set to shutdown after a certain amount of inactivity then restart when a request comes in (which I think it is the default) then this will only work if you have visits around the clock.

If you need an example of how to do this ASP.NET let me know.